# Parse XML from an online source

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I'm attempting to parse the xml located at view-source:http://www.parkrun.com.au/wp-content/themes/parkrun/xml/geo.xml.  This is my first attempt at doing this type of thing so my knowledge is limited.  I've parsed plenty of websites but not xml.

I've attempted the following code but keep getting an error:

```
Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument
xdoc.LoadXml("http://www.parkrun.com.au/wp-content/themes/parkrun/xml/geo.xml")
```

Error: {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}

What I'm attempting to do is parse the xml and then loop through the records to build an array based on each location and state (eg from below it would be ipswichqld, Queensland).  For example below ipswichqld belongs to Queensland (r="4" joins with id="4").

Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `LoadXml()` method, you should've used [`XmlDocument.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to load XML from local or online source file :

```
Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument
xdoc.Load("http://www.parkrun.com.au/wp-content/themes/parkrun/xml/geo.xml")
```

Unfortunately, particular website you're trying to load XML from [doesn't allow this operation](http://www.parkrun.com/scraping/) (<s>not even if you open that XML URL from browser</s>). I got this exception when trying above code :

> **WebException**
>
> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: At least I was close, bugger, that's not very nice of them :(, I might have to add the XML text as a resource and manually update it when it changes.  I had hoped to automate it but looks like that won't work.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I just noticed part of your comment, I seem to be able to open that URL just fine from my browser, not sure why you couldn't...